# How to pack png into zip correctly with JSZIP

Tags: javascript, jszip

Trying to use jszip to pack png image in zip for user to download (FileSaver.js)
https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

here is my code :

```
var zip = new JSZip()
var ship_previews = zip.folder('gui/ship_previews')
var ship_previews_ds = zip.folder('gui/ship_previews_ds')

// packing files to zip
let selectedList = $('.mixitup select')
for (let i = 0; i < selectedList.length; i++) {
  const imageID = selectedList[i].value
  if (imageID.substring(8) != 0) {
    let imageFile = $.get('assets/images/ship_previews/' + imageID + '.png')
    ship_previews.file(imageID.substring(0, 7) + '.png', imageFile)
    let imageFileDS = $.get('assets/images/ship_previews_ds/' + imageID + '.png')
    ship_previews_ds.file(imageID.substring(0, 7) + '.png', imageFileDS)
  }
}

// download zip
zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'})
.then(function(content) {
  saveAs(content, 'res_mod.zip')
})
```

And after run it

It downloaded a zip file with folders

But png inside cant read :((

Comment: `$.get()` returns results asynchronously

Comment: I have put a console log before zip.generateAsync and it return datas that I put in, so I think datas all packed in zip and can be download, but in some reason make png in zip cant read after unzip.

Comment: Is `imageFile` at `ship_previews.file(imageID.substring(0, 7) + '.png', imageFile)` expected to be a jQuery promise object?

Comment: I dont know what is jQuery promise, but data in zip looks like `_data:Promise` and `PromiseValue:Unit8Array`

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get